# Value from array object is not passing from Link to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking for the help to pass the data from one component  to another component from link to in react router. What I nee is to take me to another page Newscontent when I click Link button in Titlecard with its values in item array object

App.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
            <Route path="newscontent" element={<Newscontent />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Titlecard.js

```
const Titlecard = ({
  item: {
    id,
    imagePath,
    category,
    contentTitle,
    newsContent,
    authorName,
    time,
  },
}) => {
  return (
 <>
 <Link to={"/Newscontent"}
       state={{ item }}         
       >
       Read Article
</Link>
```

Newscontent.js

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Newscontent = (props) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location);
  return <div>Articles dsfkdijsf sdjfdjsfjsd sdiofjidsjf</div>;
};
export default Newscontent;
```

Answer (score 1):

use `useNavigation` hook

```
const navigation = useNavigation()

const linkClick = () => {
   navigation.navigate('Newscontent', {state:item})
}

  return (
 <>
 <Link onClick={linkClick }      
       >
       Read Article
</Link>
```

Now use `useParams` to get the data

```
const Newscontent = (props) => {
  const {state}= useParams();
  console.log(state)
```

Answer (score 0):

as the [react-router v5 documentation](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) shows, you need to put the state inside the `to` props

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/courses",
    search: "?sort=name",
    hash: "#the-hash",
    state: { fromDashboard: true }
  }}
/>
```